# Custom Lists get duplicated and distorted after add-in update

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, custom-list

We have a SharePoint add-in with a page consisting of several custom lists. The add-in works correctly if installed from scratch, you can add information to the various lists, and work with it for weeks with no issues. The problem is that once you update the add-in, all the custom lists get duplicated and the formatting of the lists gets distorted. So after updating the add-in, all the data that was entered in those lists previously, becomes unusable.
We've tried using ReplaceContent = TRUE to avoid duplication on update, and we also followed everything in this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn265911.aspx with no success.
 
We're always running the app in SharePoint Online, updating the .app can take place through appcatalog or the Office store with same results.
I would really appreciate any ideas or direction on this.
 
Thanks,
Arik